# Lambda expression using Join for something more than a simple key

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'd like to do a Join but I need to compare more than just a simple key. For example, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
from a in tableA
join b in tableB on a.x between b.minX and b.maxX
```

Not very complicated. But the functions for the Join lambda method seem to want a simple key to compare.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not simply use an appropriate `where clause`?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and what you'd hope to see?

Comment: @Tim I don't think there is a appropriate where clause, because I'm trying to Join two tables -- so the values that go into the where clause would change according to the row in the first table.

Comment: (I think my formatting preserved the initial idea).  Do you want to do something like a `left outer join` to `tableB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from a in tableA
from b in tableB
where a >= b.minX && a <= b.maxX
select a;
```

Comment: Is this even legal? And what is the lambda expression equivalent?

Comment: @Fernando: Of course it's legal, it's a Cartesian join and a filter on the result.  And what do you mean by "lambda expression equivalent?"

Comment: example: myThings.Where(thing => thing <= 25)

Comment: @Fernando: A double from clause translates to a `SelectMany`, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var fdts = from fdt in context.FeuilleDeTemps.Include("FeuilleDeTempsJournees")
           where
               (employes.Contains(fdt.ID_Employe)) &&
               (fdt.DateDepart <= date) &&
               (fdt.DateFin >= date)
           orderby fdt.ID_Employe
           select fdt;
```

or in your case

```
var v = from a in context.tableA.Include("tableB")
        where
            a.x < b.minX &&
            a.x > b.maxX
        select v;
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked specifically for the dotted syntax?

```
        var tableA = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
        var tableB = new[]
                         {
                             new {minX = 1, maxX = 2},
                             new {minX = 3, maxX = 6},
                             new {minX = 5, maxX = 7},
                             new {minX = 6, maxX = 8},
                         };
        var res = tableA.SelectMany(a => tableB, (a, b) => new {a, b}).Where(t => t.a >= t.b.minX && t.a <= t.b.maxX)
                .Select(t => t.a);
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional help!

Comment: You're welcome. You can, of course, optimize by putting in the check predicate within the first argument passed to SelectMany, ie "a=>tableB.Where(b=>((a<b.maxX)&&(a>b.minX))) " so you don't have to new() the tuple before checking.